# Facebook redirect uri when logging in from mobile on my site shows this error even when the redirect uri is whitelisted

Tags: reactjs, facebook

I have a site https://gigsy.in, here the login using fb is working in Desktop and laptop but for some reason the same on mobile phone using any browser gives the following error.

```
URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. 
Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.
```

Note that this only happens on **mobile** and not on Desktop or laptop.

I have checked the APP_ID and CLIENT_ID, they are correct.
Also I have whitelisted the redirect_uri https://gigsy.in/login

Comment: Are you staying on that main domain with mobile devices, or do you maybe have an extra mobile version of your site on a subdomain, that you redirect to? Server-side or client-side login flow?

Comment: Nah everything is same for both mobile and desktop

Answer (score 0):

You must put disableMobileRedirect to true. [image]